# Update a variable that changes the UI from background thread - SWIFTUI

Tags: swift, multithreading, swiftui, thread-safety, apple-developer

What is the correct way to notify the main thread, that the background-thread operations are finished?

I get this error now:

```swiftUI
Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
```

Here is where i make the background-queue-operations:

```swiftUI
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    //the thumbnail
    @Published var image: UIImage?

    //value to verify everything is loaded
    @Published var isLoaded = false
    
    
    private(set) var isLoading = false

    
    func load() {
        
        let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ThumbNailMaker", qos: .background)
        
        dispatchQueue.async {
            self.removeChar()
            self.createThumbnailOfVideoFromRemoteUrl()
            self.isLoaded = true     //<--------------------- Here the error appears
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace the `self.isLoaded = true` with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.isLoaded = true }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply offload that work back to the main thread:

```
self.createThumbnailOfVideoFromRemoteUrl()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.isLoaded = true 
}
```